# I want my navbar to disappear when I scroll down and appear when I scroll up. The navbar is fixed. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var nav_offset_top = $('.header_area').height()+50;
function navbarFixed(){
    if ( $('.header_area').length )
    {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= nav_offset_top ) {
                $(".header_area").addClass("navbar_fixed");
            } else {
                $(".header_area").removeClass("navbar_fixed");
            }
        });
    };
};
navbarFixed();
```

How to fix this? when I scroll, the navbar is actually fixed on the same position instead of getting hidden.

Comment: Try to check if the $(.header_area) is being fetched correctly. Seems like the scroll listener should work well, as long as it passes if case. So there might be a typo in your DOM.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Please create a snippet for your code (html/css/js)

Comment: I would check to see what the value of `nav_offset_top` is when each scroll is firing. Its possible that its 0 and was only calculated once during the initial run of the script. Sometimes (if say, you haven't properly used an IIFE) the script runs before the DOM loads and the actual height is there to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace h1 tag with your navbar and set id to your navbar and add css as well**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
    document.getElementById("m-id").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("m-id").className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
body{
height:1500px;
}
.test {
  background-color: yellow;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>nav-disappear</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="m-id" style="position:fixed">This will be your Navbar</h1>
<p>scroll down to see magic in navbar</p>
</body>
</html>
```